# Now.ToFileTime() returns same time at different calls

Tags: vb.net, datetime, timestamp

I have a program that uses the `Now.ToFileTime()` function in .NET to get a time-stamp for a file name. I've verified that this code is called on only 1 thread so I'm not worried about concurrency.

I have the following test code in my method:

```
Dim Time As String = Now.ToFileTime()
IO.File.AppendAllText("D:\test.txt", Time & " - " & System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId().ToString() & vbCrLf)
```

This ends up outputting the following to test.txt:

```
129899740120622239 - 4
129899740140465735 - 4
129899740140465735 - 4
129899740140465735 - 4
129899740140465735 - 4
129899740160465479 - 4
129899740160465479 - 4
129899740160621727 - 4
129899740160621727 - 4
```

So you can see that the time-stamp repeats itself 2 or more times. Occasionally I will get a unique one, but not very often. Shouldn't I be getting unique times each time I call this method. The alls are at least a few mills apart. I don't just invoke it sequentially (but even then I would expect to get different times).

Comment: _"...then  I would expect to get different times"_ The resolution of DateTime.Now depends on your system timer (~10ms on a current Windows OS), so it's giving the same value there. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/04/08/precision-and-accuracy-of-datetime.aspx

Comment: Do you use the Timestamp just for uniqueness or has it some other purpose in the file names?

Comment: Its for uniqueness and to indicate time. Is there any way to up the resolution of date-time, or is this a bad idea. If I shouldn't/can't do that then I suppose I'll just have to integrate an index into the time-stamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a global variable and ensure it has changed before using it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Everyone,

Given the resolution of system time pointed out by Tim; I put in a private static variable as an index to ensure uniquness.